# click - only on "direct" onclicks

Tags: jquery

If you put a .click() on a div element and you got an input element in the div.. how can you then omit the .click() if the user clicks on the input?

The div.click() only has to trigger when the user click inside the div, but outside the input element

```
<div style="width:400px; height:200px">
<input type="text" style="width:50px" />
</div>
```

Comment: Here's the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183381/how-to-have-click-event-only-fire-on-parent-div-not-children `if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) return`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two choices:

Attach a `click` event handler to the input element and prevent the event from bubbling up by calling [`event.stopPropagation()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
$('input').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

OR

Inspect the [`event.target` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) in the `click` event handler attached to the `div` whether the target is the `input` element or not. Something like:

```
if(event.target.nodeName !== 'INPUT') {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: never knew about `event.stopPropagation();` Very nice, +1 =P

Answer (score 4):

you can use this:

```
if(event.toElement != this)
    return;
```

Comment: Example code for Jquery: `$('.mybutton').click( function(e){ if(e.toElement==$(this)[0]) { // do stuff } });`

Answer (score 0):

To make it work only on direct clicks, do this:

for jquery:

```js
$(".background").click(() => {
    console.log("background got clicked");
});

$(".background > *").click((event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

for vanilla js:

```js
document.querySelector(".background").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    console.log("background got clicked");
});

let backgroundChildren = document.querySelectorAll(".background > *");

backgroundChildren.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```