# how to click() only clicked DIV, not containing DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="firstDiv" style="width:1000px;height:600px;">
    <div id="secondDiv" style="width:200px;height:200px;"></div>
</div>
```

Both DIVs have click() events. When I click secondDiv, the click-event for firstDiv is also fired (I guess that is logic since I also clicked within firstDiv's borders). I however only want to fire the click-event for the DIV that I actually had my mouse over upon clicking.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015041/two-differents-onclick-on-two-divs-one-over-the-other

Comment: possible duplicate of [click - only on "direct" onclicks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512803/click-only-on-direct-onclicks)

Comment: [`event.stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the inner div add:

```
$('#secondDiv').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
```

[`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) will prevent the click event from bubbling up from inner div to the parent div or any other ancestor.

Answer (score 5):

DOM elements by default bubbles up the events. You can stop by using stopPropagation

```
$('#secondDiv').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: @user125697 I think you used `preventDefault`. You should be using `stopPropagation`

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this -

```
$('#secondDiv').click(function(event) {
    // do your stuff
    return false;
 });
```

`return false;` is the equivalent to `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 1):

You'll want use [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) which will prevent the event from bubbling up to parent elements (in your case). The `preventDefault` looks promising but it actually prevents default actions - not bubbling.

```
$("#firstDiv").click(function() {
  alert("Div One");
});

$("#secondDiv").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert("Div Two");
});
```

Demo of both [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ATmTe/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.stopPropagation()` for this bubbling. Something like this:

```
$("secondDiv").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
   //Write your logic here
});
```

For more information on this refer to the documentation [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)